# Forground service and workmanager notification continues to show even after stopping the workmanager

Tags: android-service, android-notifications, kotlin-coroutines, android-workmanager

This is a simple example of workmanager as a forground service. The problem is that forground notification is showing even after the workmanager is stopped. I feel like the problem is related to coroutines memory leak.

```
@HiltWorker
class MyForegroundWorker @AssistedInject constructor(
    @Assisted context: Context,
    @Assisted workerParams: WorkerParameters
) : CoroutineWorker(context, workerParams) {

    private lateinit var notificationBuilder: NotificationCompat.Builder
    private var i: Long = 0

    private val notificationManager =
        context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager

    override suspend fun doWork(): Result =  withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        setForeground(createForegroundInfo())
        return@withContext runCatching {

            while (true) {
                updateNotification(i.toString())
                i += 1

            }
            Result.success()
        }.getOrElse {

            Log.d("TAG", "doWork: ${it.message}, ${i}")
            Result.failure()
        }
    }


//..


}
```

Comment: Hi, Your while loop for showing notification doesn't have an exit condition. It always true. Thus the worker is always within the loop. This is what I see from the code snippet. Correct me if am wrong. Thanks

Comment: Yes, the only way to stop the work manager is by cancelling it.